# asp.net mvc search component for static pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, search, search-engine

I'm looking for a good search component to plug in to an ASP.NET MVC 2 website.

I've seen a few non-mvc ones before. Our website is comprised of 99% static mvc pages so I need something that will index and search the entire site (and not use database fulltext search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success with Wrensoft's [Zoom Search](http://www.wrensoft.com/zoom/) Engine.  Works with ASP.NET and it is inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider http://www.google.com/sitesearch/ or if you want more customization you can look into a lucene.net based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Google Search Appliance http://www.google.com/gsa

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Google search, Have a look at Bing Live search too. Its api is available [here](http://www.bing.com/developers)